# SCSS not properly passing relative image references on import from different folder

Tags: css, import, sass

I'm developing a site using SCSS, and relative image paths aren't working properly when I import files. Here's what I mean:

**Directory structure**

```
./
    css/
        main-code.scss
        common/
            include.scss
    images/
        image.jpg
```

**include.scss**

```
body {
    background-image: url('../../images/image.jpg');
}
```

**main-code.scss**

```
@import("common/include.scss");
```

My include.scss file includes a proper relative reference to image.jpg. But when I import it into main-code.scss, which sits in a different directory, the link to the image is broken because it still appears as `url('../../images/image.jpg')` — which is no longer a valid reference to the image if we start up a folder in the directory structure.

Is there any way to include a SCSS file and automatically adjust relative paths appropriately? Or do I need to put both of my SCSS files in one folder for this to function properly?

Comment: paths are **always relative to the FINAL CSS file** since that's what the browser reads and interacts with. If you're using something like Webpack to parse the SCSS -> CSS it has some helpers for paths. But based on what you have `./images/` should allow the page to find the image files.

Comment: sorry, should be `../images/` everywhere in your CSS files. Had a typo that I missed before

Comment: Got it. Is there any way to adapt the path based on where my final CSS file lives? The problem here is that I might also want to access the common file from a file that lives in a folder that's different from the one that main-code sits in.

Comment: It only matters where your final .CSS file lives. So where ever that file ends up. Make your image paths relative to its path. The directory structure of the SCSS files doesn't matter. That said, look into Webpack or Compass as those tools will make your life a lot easier.

Comment: Got it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is how i fixed it:

```
$default_path_dept: '../../' !default;
```

Then some css values

```
background: #fff url('#{$default_path_dept}default/img/textbox-valid.png')
```

Then in file in other, higher directory

```
$default_path_dept: '../../../../';
@import "#{$default_path_dept}default/css/global.scss";
```

This way you can fix missing images